# image list giving, ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I am trying to load some images,but when i try to do so, i get this error

the code looks like this:

```
color_me = []
for filename in os.listdir('/home/decentmakeover2/Coloring-greyscale-images-in-Keras/floydhub/Test/'):

color_me.append(img_to_array(load_img('/home/decentmakeover2/Coloring-
greyscale-images-in-Keras/floydhub/Test/'+filename)))
color_me = np.array(color_me, dtype=float)
color_me = rgb2lab(1.0/255*color_me)[:,:,:,0]
color_me = color_me.reshape(color_me.shape+(1,))
```

but i get this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0650ed3793a3> in <module>()
     77 for filename in os.listdir('/home/decentmakeover2/Coloring-
greyscale-images-in-Keras/floydhub/Test/'):
     78         
color_me.append(img_to_array(load_img('/home/decentmakeover2/Coloring-greyscale-images-in-Keras/floydhub/Test/'+filename)))
---> 79 color_me = np.array(color_me, dtype=float)
     80 color_me = rgb2lab(1.0/255*color_me)[:,:,:,0]
     81 color_me = color_me.reshape(color_me.shape+(1,))

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The color_me list has 2 images,any suggestions on what may be wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Numpy are you using?  Do the contents of each image have the shape and dtype you're expecting?

Comment: The version is 1.12.1,about the shape im not too sure,but now that you pointed out the input shape of the image,i checked and its not( 256,256,1),I'm guessing that's the problem.Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome.  Consider [posting an answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you've resolved it successfully.

Comment: getting `setting an array element with a sequence` error from `np.array(...)` usually means a dimension mismatch. Are your images all the same shape?

Comment: They were not,will post a self answer in some time.thanks for your time.